# UITextView avoid text selection, but keep tappable links

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink, uitextfield, uiviewrepresentable

I have a pop-up window, that shows terms of service & privacy policy for users, how to disable text selection but keep links tappable. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2eBy.png)
If I set:
SOLVED: By adding textViewDidChangeSelection method in UIViewDelegate and setting

```
textView.isSelectable = false
textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
textView.isSelectable = true
```

Links become uninteractable.
How do I keep the link tappable and text not selectable?

My whole class:

```
//  HyperLinkTextView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct Hyperlink {
    var word: String
    var url: NSURL
}

struct HyperLinkTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    private var text: String
    private var links: [Hyperlink]
    let textView = UITextView()
    
    init(text: String, links: [Hyperlink]) {
        self.text = text
        self.links = links
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> UITextView {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        links.forEach { hyperlink in
            let linkAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.link: hyperlink.url]
            
            var nsRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0)
            if let range = text.range(of: hyperlink.word) {
                nsRange = NSRange(range, in: text)
            }
            
            attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributes, range: nsRange)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: NSNumber(value: 1), range: nsRange)
        }
        
        textView.isEditable = false
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.attributedText = attributedString
        textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(Theme.colorClickables)]
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textView.isSelectable = true
    
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.font = UIFont(name: "ArialMT", size: 18)
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
    
    
    public class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate, NSLayoutManagerDelegate {
        
        weak var textView: UITextView?
            
        public func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
            return true
        }
        
        func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
            if textView.selectedTextRange != nil {
                textView.delegate = nil
                textView.selectedTextRange = nil
                textView.delegate = self
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this `UITextViewDelegate` `textViewDidChangeSelection` and comment out `isEditable` and `isSelectable`:

```
func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.selectedTextRange != nil {
        textView.delegate = nil
        textView.selectedTextRange = nil
        textView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Not works for me, i place this func under my public class Coordinator, public func textView(), right ?

Comment: @ItaiAviv isUserInteractionEnabled enabled ??

Comment: @ItaiAviv  how you are using in SwiftUI and update the question with the source.

Comment: @ItaiAviv Are these `isEditable` `isUserInteractionEnabled` `isSelectable`, still false in the codebase ?

Comment: isEditable = false
isUserInteractionEnabled = true
isSelectable = false
So now all text is unselectable & links untapable

Comment: @ItaiAviv comment out iseditable and isSelectable

Comment: if i comment out this properties, text become editable and selectable

Comment: Have you tried commenting out, that's the reason we're setting delegate = nil in `textViewDidChangeSelection` ?

Comment: @ItaiAviv  true it ain't work. I've updated the code block, and keep those settings enabled.

Comment: wow, works for me, when set  `isEditable = false`, `isUserInteractionEnabled = true `, `isSelectable = true `, and use your code block, thx)

Comment: @ItaiAviv Great!! you can consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Works for me in Xcode 15.2, Swift 5.

Comment: This still shows the magnifying glass.